# Not able to find static file with GCP app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I am trying to deploy a flask app with bootstrap and Jinja2 on GCP app engine. I have a css file for custom style of bootstrap template. The deployment was succeeded and the app worked fine except this custom.css, which I get a 404 error from app engine dashboard.

It works fine locally, so I am guessing there is something wrong with my app.yaml configuration.

My project directory structure is like this:

```
app
|
|-static
|   |-custom.css
|
|-templates
|   |-base.html
|
|  __init__.py
|  auth.py
|  functions.py
|  main.py
|  app.yaml
|  requirements.txt
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: public

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="/static/custom.css"
    />
  </head>
```

I am quite new to GCP and also unfamiliar with yaml, any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Edit:
Sorry I forgot to mentioned that I tried following approach and didn't work as well:

```
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a folder called `public` and python3 doesn't have that concept but your app.yaml is referring to a `public` folder.

In app.yaml, make the change for your static handler to

```
    - url: /static
    static_dir: static
```

Extra Information:

1. Your local environment is not always an exact replica of GAE Production. It is at best a simulation. So don't always assume what works in local will work in production.
2. Bullet 1 is especially important if you are not running your local environment with `dev_appserver.py` command. For example, if you test on your local environment using the command - `python run XXXX`, `flask run XXX`, then you are not using a `GAE Simulated environment` and thus are not using `app.yaml`

Comment: no offense, but `dev_appserver.py` is extremely deprecated. It's python 2

Comment: @EdoAkse -  You can now run python3 apps with ```dev_appserver.py``` (not supported on Windows). See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/tools/local-devserver-command

Comment: consider me rebuked. Good to know, TYVM

Comment: and the thing is still written in python2. Just, wow...

Comment: @EdoAkse - yeah :) There are multiple requests to rewrite in Python 3 so that if you're running Python 3 Apps, you don't have to keep Python 2 installed (can't remember if Google has agreed/started work on it)

Comment: Thank you for the extra materials. This is really some helpful knowledge for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the mismatch of the folder names in your app.yaml:

```yaml
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: public
```

What you're doing here is pointing the external `/static` path to the internal `public` path. Since the path `public` doesn't exist in your app, it will return a 404 not found error.

Change the `static_dir` value to `static` and it will work...

[These docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/serving-static-files#configuring_your_static_file_handlers) are not exactly clear on this, but [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) for app.yaml explain it nicely (see the section about `static_dir`)

### EDIT after comments

So I did some testing to be sure, see below for files used. I changed the local folder name to `not_static` to make sure that the `/.*` url handler in my `app.yaml` didn't actually trigger. Deploying this and looking at the website, I can see the `style.css` being correctly loaded. (I know I''m not using it, this was just testing. The HTML is the literal hello world from w3schools...)

As you can see in the screenshot, the `style.css` is downloaded correctly.
[image: style.css]

The issue might be with caching, as that can be *fun* at times. But it *should* work...

**my file structure**

```
/not_static
  └> style.css
app.yaml
requirements.txt
main.py
```

**app.yaml**

```yaml
runtime: python39
service: testing123

instance_class: F1
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: not_static
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

**main.py**

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
"""
```

**requirements.txt**

```
flask
gunicorn
```

**/not_static/style.css**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Aclonica&family=Comfortaa:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Electrolize&family=Goldman:wght@400;700&family=Varela+Round&display=swap&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap");


:root {
    --text-color: #333333;
    --background-color: #eaeaea;
  }
  
  body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry I forgot to mention I tried this approach and it was also not working. I just tried to deploy again with only this line altered and still no custom style showed.

Comment: not exactly sure what is happening on your end, testing I've done shows that it *should* work. See my edit...

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I still get a 404 from chrome inspection for my custom.css, even I double checked that I did upload it or disabled caching. I truly think your approach should work theoretically, will continue looking for some solutions to get pass this....